# angular universal not working even on empty project

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

i build it simply using

```
ng new test-ssr
cd test-ssr
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject test-ssr
npm run build:ssr
npm run serve:ssr
```

when i go to localhost:4000 it shows

```
Error: You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be bootstrapped
    at View.engine (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:39238:23)
    at View.render (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:123884:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:121592:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:121544:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:130425:7)
    at C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:135:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:123312:5)
    at next (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:123060:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:123035:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rober\ng\test-ssr\dist\server.js:123312:5)
```

updated all dependencies using `ng update --all --force` then `npm i typescript@">=3.1.1 <3.3"` also didn't solve anything (tried before and after)

note that running `npm start` and opening localhost:4200 still works normally

you can see my version here
https://github.com/robertisaacBBN/ng-ssr

Comment: I tried with your version and I don't have this error. Can you check if you have the flag `--prod` when running the build?

Comment: please see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13865

Comment: its a problem with `@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.5`

Comment: @JohanRin you cloned the repo and the problem didn't happen with you?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I did the following command: `git clone https://github.com/robertisaacBBN/ng-ssr.git && cd ng-ssr && npm install && npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` and after checked in my browser with the `http://localhost:4000` url

Comment: what's your OS
i'm using windows 10 64 bit

Comment: also run `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest` first and make sure the version is 0.13.5

Comment: I'm running on macOS Mojave v10.14.3 and I don't need to update the @angular-devkit because It worked without your change.

Comment: i changed the package.json in the repo and set the target of the angular-devkit to 0.13.4 so it will not install 0.13.5 which has the problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

its an issue with angular

simply run `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.4` to solve the issues

see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13865 to track the issue